# Use TikZ externalization and draft-mode with XeTeX

Tags: xetex, tikz-external

I try to use `\tikzexternalize` and the documents `draft` mode in XeTeX.

```
%% tikzext.tex
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (1,1) -- (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I also tried to add this lines because I saw it in another report - but don't know whtat they do.

```
\tikzset{external/system call={%
    xelatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape
    -halt-on-error -shell-escape -interaction=batchmode
-jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
```

I call my XeTeX this way from inside `vim`: `xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode`

This is the error produced:

```
! Package tikz Warning: The key 'up to date check=md5' is impossible, 

there is 
no macro to compute MD5. Falling back to 'up to date check=diff'.
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'xelatex -halt-on-error -intera
ction=batchmode -jobname "tikzext-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{tikzext}\i
nput{tikzext}"' ========

! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'xelatex -halt-on-error -interacti
on=batchmode -jobname "tikzext-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{tikzext}\inpu
t{tikzext}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'tikzext-figure0' (expected
 one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:.bmp:). Please verify that you have enabled system
 calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also na
med 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Erro
r messages can be found in 'tikzext-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try
 to typeset the picture.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.19 \end{tikzpicture}

[1] (./tikzext.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on tikzext.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on tikzext.log.
```

I also tried to link `/usr/bin/md5` to `/usr/bin/md5sum` - without an effect.
The log-file mentioned in the output doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a lot of help from other people here a solution.

`xelatex` should be called with `-shell-escape`. This actives `\write18`. I don't know what this means but it works.

Please feel free to edit this answer to add more technical details.

Comment: I try to use this settings: `xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --enable-write18 -shell-escape --extra-mem-bot=20000000 %.tex`
but without any effect.